# Azure AD B2C App Service Auth password reset

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to implement azure B2C using the new App Service Auth workflow as described here:
https://cgillum.tech/2016/05/27/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c/

Signup and login is working fine, but password reset redirects to the same url as a successful login. 
For example: https://myapp.azurewebsite.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

But given that the user not logged in this redirect fails with a `401 Unauthorized` error.

I have set up a password reset policy in my Azure B2C tenant but there seems to be no way to redirect the Easy Auth system to it.

Note that I also enabled password reset for the B2C in the classic portal.

What am I missing here?

**Update:**
When I use a SignIn policy only (not a combined SignUp/SignIn policy) the password reset works fine. These two policies seem to do different things.

Comment: This is exactly what's happening to me.  One says `Forgot Password?` and the other says `Can't access account?`  They do two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE 8/15/2016

See this blog post for more information on how to invoke additional B2C policies from your App Service app (includes examples): https://cgillum.tech/2016/08/10/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c-part-2/

Here is an example of how you can invoke a password reset policy from within your web app:

```
<a href="/.auth/login/aad?p=B2C_1_ResetPassword&post_login_redirect_uri=/">Reset Password</a>
```

---

### Old response - please disregard:

You may be running into a temporary limitation of the integrated B2C support in App Service, as mentioned in the blog post:~~

> We currently only support a single B2C policy at a time for your app. The example I showed previously uses a single Sign-up or Sign-in policy. This should work out nicely for many apps but may be limiting if you want to go deeper with B2C...
>
> This will add support for these B2C scenarios very soon in a future service update. I’ll update this blog post when we get those updates out and demonstrates how to take advantage of them.

Expect an update by the end of this week or early next week. A new blog post will be added which shows how to use multiple policies and even gives examples, including password reset.

Comment: Updated with the new information! This should hopefully get you going.

Comment: I'm using combined signup and signin policies with easy auth enabled on the deployment slot. I cannot refresh the token. Is it because I'm using combined signup and signin policy?

Comment: @HarishMashetty I don't think that should matter. Try enabling application logging to see why the refresh failed. Most likely there is some App Service auth configuration you are missing.

Comment: @ChrisGillum Thanks for the reply. Refresh is intermittently working. There's another issue with easy auth using combined signup and sign in policy, 'forgot password' link doesn't work. Is this a known issue?

Comment: @HarishMashetty the 'forgot password' issue is a known issue. Take a look at the comments in the blog post to find the workaround.

Comment: @ChrisGillum Thanks for the reply. I'm using msal.js now instead of EasyAuth. Also I'm wondering if there would be support in the future for adding two facebook identity providers (facebook social and facebook enterprise) to a b2c tenant.

Comment: @HarishMashetty I'm not sure about that one. I recommend you ask that as a separate question. The B2C experts should be able to find your question and provide the right answer.